# How do i check if something exist without using count(*) ... limit 1

Tags: sql-server

My code is `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  name_list  WHERE  [name]='a'  LIMIT 1`

It appears there is no limit clause in SQL Server. So how do i say tell me if 'a' exist in name_list.name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM name_list WHERE name = 'a')
BEGIN
    -- such a record exists
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- such a record does not exist
END
```

Points to note:

- don't worry about the `SELECT *` - the database engine knows what you are asking
- the `IF` is just for illustration - the `EXISTS(SELECT ...)` expression is what answers your question
- the `BEGIN` and `END` are strictly speaking unnecessary if there is only one statement in the block

Answer (score 3):

COUNT(*) returns a single row anyway, no need to limit.
The ANSI equivalent for LIMIT is TOP: `SELECT TOP(1) ... FROM ... WHERE...`
And finally, there is EXISTS: `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ... WHERE  ...)`.

Comment: In SQL Server, top goes without parenthesis.

Comment: @jpabluz: SQL Server 2005+ supports brackets around TOP criteria, in order to support a variable being used.

Comment: @jpabluz: "Parentheses that delimit expression in TOP is **required** in INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements. For backward compatibility, TOP expression  without parentheses in SELECT statements is **supported**, but we do **not recommend** this.". From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No nono that is wrong.

First there is top, so you have to say something like:

```
select top 1 1 from name_list where [name]='a'
```

You'll get a row with only a unnamed field with 1 out of the query if there is data, and no rows at all if there is no data.

Answer (score 0):

The `TOP` clause is the closest equivalent to `LIMIT`.  The following will return all of the fields in the first row whose name field equals 'a' (altough if more than one row matches, the row that ets returned will be undefined unless you also provide an `ORDER BY` clause).

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM name_list WHERE [name]='a'
```

But there's no need to use it if you're doing a `COUNT(*)`.  The following will return a single row with a single field that is number of rows whose name field eqals 'a' in the whole table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM name_list WHERE [name]='a'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (EXISTS(SELECT [name] FROM name_list where [name] = 'a'))
begin
   //do other work if exists
end
```

You can also do the opposite:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT [name] FROM name_list where [name] = 'a'))
begin
   //do other work if not exists
end
```

Comment: Use caution with these, there are some enterprise applications that don't fully support IF clauses.

Answer (score 0):

This query returns exactly what you intended:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * WHERE [name] = 'a') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM name_list
```